# Scala: Ignore Future return value, but chain them

Tags: scala, future, for-comprehension

How should I write code, when I do not care about the returned value.

Example:

```
for {
    a <- getA // I do not care about a, but I need to wait for the future to finish
    b <- getB
} yield (b)
```

Comment: Just like that, really.. You *could* write `_ <- getA` to stress that you don't care about the result of `getA`, but functionally, they are the same.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Like this

```
for {
     _ <- getA 
     b <- getB
} yield (b)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can you tell me, what the use of _ is called?

Comment: It is a wildcard in place of a formal parameter.  See Scala Reference, Sec. 6.23.

Answer (score 2):

Or if not a for comprehension fan, can do

```
getA.flatMap(_ => getB )
```

But I think most people will vote for comprehension

Comment: b.map(res => res) is same as b.map(identity)

Comment: @mohit genius adding.. i have never used that yet

Comment: Just `getA.flatMap(_ => getB)` should be enough (for any sane case `getB.map(identity)` should behave the same as `getB`).